# Add created on while copying data from SQL to azure data lake gen 2

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I want to copy the data to SQL from csv file in ADLS gen2. In Sql table, there is a column called `created on`. But csv file doesn't have that column. How can I copy the current date in created on along with other columns?

Comment: add a column in source settings of copy activity and give the dynamic value as `@utcnow()`

Comment: Otherwise, Add a derived column transformation in dataflow and add the new column and give the data as `currentUTC()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can add a column in source settings of copy activity and give the dynamic value as `@utcnow()`
   or
2. Add a derived column transformation in dataflow and add the new column and give the data as `currentUTC()`

**Method:1** [Using Copy Activity]

- Copy activity is taken and in source settings, source dataset is taken.

[image]

- Then Additional columns **+New** is clicked. Created_on is given in Name and `@utcnow()` is given as dynamic content.

[image]

- After adding new column, **preview data of source dataset** looks as in below image.

[image]

- After this, file can be copied to sink.

**Method:2** [Using Dataflow]

- Source data is taken as in below image in dataflow.
  [image]
- Derived column transformation is added and **+ADD** is selected in columns.  `currentUTC()` is given in the expression.
  [image]

[image]

- By this way, you can add the column dynamically whenever the data is copied to SQL.